# Meaningful errors during parsing with FSyacc

Tags: f#, error-handling, fsyacc

I'm using fsyacc/fslex from F# Power Pack to parse some source code.

To detect errors I use the following code:

```
use inputChannel = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead tempFileName)
let lexbuf = Lexing.LexBuffer<_>.FromTextReader inputChannel

let ast = try
                Parser.start Lexer.tokenize lexbuf
              with e ->
                let pos = lexbuf.EndPos
                let line = pos.Line
                let column = pos.Column
                let message = e.Message
                let lastToken = new System.String(lexbuf.Lexeme)
                printf "Parse failed at line %d, column %d:\n" line column
                printf "Last loken: %s" lastToken
                printf "\n"
                exit 1
```

But when this code throws the error message on parsing multi-line source file, I'm getting wrong line and column position:

```
Parse failed at line 0, column 10899:
```

How can I get line number correctly on which error has been occurred?

Comment: Why not debug it ? Also you can add fslex project to debug it too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

During lexing, you need to manually increment the line number with a rule like

```
...
let newline = ('\n' | '\r' '\n')

rule tokenize = parse
| newline    { lexbuf.EndPos <- lexbuf.EndPos.NextLine; tokenize lexbuf }
...
```

Comment: Yes, I have such rule for lexer.

Comment: Hmm, maybe your newline case is not matching for some reason - it's hard to debug fslex lexing, but I would double check that your actually newlines are correct for your newline regex. And maybe you can add a printf statement to see if you are actually going into the newline case (maybe you never reach it because of an earlier rule consuming the newline token?)

Comment: Yeah, you were right. I corrupted newlines before parsing. Thank you :)